# angularjs localstorage not working properly?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage

I used local storage. When I go on the page the first time, I am getting an old local storage value. When I refresh I am getting the current value. How can I avoid this error? Every time I only need the current local storage value. I have enclosed this a bit with this code. I have not installed ngstorage. Can someone tell me, whether I need to install ngstorage ?

```js
.controller('SignInCtrl', [
         '$scope','$http' ,'$location','$window', 
        function($scope,$http, $location,$window) {
  
    $scope.signin = function() 
   { 
    
   $http.post('***', userdetails).success(function(data,response) 
    {
    var nameResponse = JSON.stringify(data.Name); 
    window.localStorage.setItem("name",nameResponse);
     
       
    })
    
   
    
            }

 }])
 
 .controller('MyprofileCtrl', [
         '$scope','$http' ,'$location','$window', 
        function($scope,$http, $location,$window) {
  
  var name=$window.localStorage.getItem("name");
 //console.log(name);
 if(name == null)
 {
  
  $scope.loginstatus ="Sign Up With Us";
  console.log($scope.loginstatus);
 }else
 {
  $scope.loginstatus ='Welcome '+ name.replace(/\"/g, "");
  console.log($scope.loginstatus);
 }
  
    
 }])
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes your correct you must use ngstorage module.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ngStorage/0.3.7/ngStorage.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myModule">
 <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <button ng-click="save()">Save</button>
        <button ng-click="load()">Load</button>
        <input type="text" ng-model="txt">
        {{myData}}
    </div>
</body>
<script>
    var myModule = angular.module("myModule", ["ngStorage"]);
    myModule.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $localStorage) {
        $scope.txt = "prabhu";
        $scope.save = function() {
         alert($scope.txt)
            $localStorage.message = $scope.txt;
        }

        $scope.load = function() {
            $scope.myData = $localStorage.message;
        }
    });
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, ngStorage is not required, I hope that the dependency for $window is injected correctly in your controllers.

Try this:

```
var app = angular.module('your-app', ['the-dependent-modules']);

app.controller('loginPageController', function($window) {
   $window.localStorage.setItem('user-name', 'John');
});

app.controller('myProfilePageController', function($window, $log) {
   var username = $window.localStorage.getItem('user-name');
   $log.debug('username : ' + username);
});
```

Comment: in your code i see a typo.. window.localStorage.setItem("name",nameResponse); shouldn't this be $window.localStorage.setItem("name",nameResponse); since the parameter in your function is function($window) and not function(window).

Comment: when i reload the page its working i think somewhere cached old value

Comment: I tried at my end its working fine for me. It should ideally overwrite the old value, can you observe the values in local storage  in the debugging window ? If the value is changing or not on setting the name in the success function?